# What is a Rust equivalent to C++'s virtual overwriting to prevent code rewriting?

Tags: rust

In C++, I've written this code:

```cpp
class MessageHandler {
    virtual MediaPlayer::Ptr handle_message(...);
    virtual RtspServer::Ptr decideRtspServer(...);
    virtual RtspClient::Ptr decideRtspClient(...);
    virtual Decoder::Ptr decideDecoder(...);
    virtual Renderer::Ptr decideRenderer(...);
};
```

This class handles a message that informs which `RtspServer`, `RtspClient`, `Decoder`, `Renderer` to use, and returns a `MediaPlayer`. I want to write `MessageHandler`s for lots of devices: Android, Windows, Linux, etc, so I can override each decision. For example, I can override `decideRenderer` to decide an specific renderer that is only available in Linux, but the rest should not be overridden as it's the same in all devices.

I'm looking to do the same in Rust: have default decisions but the ability to "override" one if needed, when implementing a `MessageHandler` for an specific device.

How can I achieve something similar in Rust? I don't care if it looks like OOP or not, I just want to prevent rewriting the same code.

Comment: Are you aware that trait methods can have default implementations?

Answer (score 0):

What speaks against trait objects? Something along the lines of this:

```
trait MessageHandler {
    handle_message(...) -> Box<MediaPlayer> {
        Box::new(DefaultMediaPlayer{})
    }
    decideRtspServer(...) -> Box<RtspServer> {
        Box::ne(DefaultRtspServer{})
    }
    // and others
};

struct LinuxMessageHandler {...}
impl MessageHandler for LinuxMessageHandler {
    handle_message(...) -> Box<MediaPlayer> {
        Box::new(LinuxSpecificMediaPlayer{})
    }
    // do not implement any other method: instead, automatically "inherit" them from MessageHandler
}
```

Then, these "trait objects" are passed around as e.g. `Box<dyn MessageHandler>`.